# How to UNION queries with different number of columns by repeating the values to fill the gap in SQL alchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a query that produces a list of object names:

```
SELECT object_name FROM Objects
```

I can easily produce this with `SqlAlchemy`:

```
query1 = session.query(Object.object_name)
```

And I have another query that produces a list of object names with their respective tags

```
SELECT object_name, tag FROM Tags
```

I can also get this easily with SqlAlchemy:

```
query2 = session.query(Tags.object_name, Tags.tag)
```

Now, I want to combine these two queries to get a list of `(object_name, name_or_tag)`, so for each object that has `N` tags, there will be `N + 1` rows. One per tag, and one that has the same value twice.

How can I `UNION` these two queries given that they have different number of columns? in raw SQL I could do something like (pseudocode):

```
SELECT object_name, object_name as name_or_tag 
FROM $query1
UNION
$query2
```

But how do I produce the first part of that `UNION` with the query I have?

I tried something that obviously doesn't work but conveys the intention:

```
union_query = (
     session
    .query(Tags.object_name, Tags.object_name.label("name_or_tag")
    .query_from(query)
)
```

But `query_from` does not take a query as an argument. What alternatives do I have to union these two queries?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are doing this but something like this seems to work, its an extension of your other question.  I'm using sqlalchemy 1.4.31.  I ordered the union so that the names lined up with the tags, I'm not sure if that was the intention or not.

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, union
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)


class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animals'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Human(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'humans'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)

class NameDirectory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'name_directories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)

class AnimalTag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animal_tags'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    tag_name = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    dog = Animal(name='Spot')
    human = Human(name='Guy')
    human2 = Human(name='Man')
    session.add_all([dog, human, human2])
    for obj in (dog, human):
        session.add(NameDirectory(name=obj.name))
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(AnimalTag(name="Spot", tag_name="dog"))
    session.add(AnimalTag(name="Guy", tag_name="human"))
    session.add(AnimalTag(name="Spot", tag_name="black-and-white"))
    session.commit()

    q1 = select([Animal.name.label('name'), Animal.name.label('name_or_tag')]).select_from(Animal)
    q2 = select([Human.name.label('name'), Human.name.label('name_or_tag')]).select_from(Human)
    q3 = select([AnimalTag.name.label('name'), AnimalTag.tag_name.label('name_or_tag')]).select_from(AnimalTag)
    sub = union(q1, q2, q3).alias()
    q = select([sub.c.name, sub.c.name_or_tag]).order_by(sub.c.name, sub.c.name_or_tag)
    print(q)
    print(session.execute(q).all())
```

```
SELECT anon_1.name, anon_1.name_or_tag 
FROM (SELECT animals.name AS name, animals.name AS name_or_tag 
FROM animals UNION SELECT humans.name AS name, humans.name AS name_or_tag 
FROM humans UNION SELECT animal_tags.name AS name, animal_tags.tag_name AS name_or_tag 
FROM animal_tags) AS anon_1 ORDER BY anon_1.name, anon_1.name_or_tag
[('Guy', 'Guy'), ('Guy', 'human'), ('Man', 'Man'), ('Spot', 'Spot'), ('Spot', 'black-and-white'), ('Spot', 'dog')]
```

Comment: For context of why I'm doing this: Imagine the name is an automagic tag, so I want to get a list of all the tags (explicit or automagical) in a query so I can join it with some other table.

The problem with your solution is that it starts from querying the initial table directly `Animal`. In my case, I don't start from a table, but from a query that can be arbitrarily complicated. All I know is that the result of the query is the list of names. So the question is how to take that `Query` object (not Model class) and repeat the column.

Comment: You should still be able to just use `select()` with `alias()`.  Is the query object not created by your code but comes from some other code ?